# how can I delete records when my disk drive is full?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, delete, disk-space, shrink

My data folder of SQL as filled up the space of my local drive. I have 150KB free space left in the drive. So I have to delete some records to regain space. But when I run the delete query it says transaction log is full and stops halfway. How can I free space? How can I delete the records? There is no available space to shrink as well. Please help

Comment: Is your transaction log on the same disk as your database's data file? Are you running regular transaction log backups?

Comment: Its in simple recovery model. Yes its in the same disk as well. But its less than the size of 2MB

Comment: Another option is to add an additional T-Log file (temporarily, don't shoot me @AaronBertrand) on a different drive that has the space.  Once everything is smoothed out you should get rid of the T-Log file that is on the same drive as the data (best practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had to replace the log file to another drive which has space. Then I was able to delete the things and shrink until I freed space in DATA drive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete in smaller chunks using a loop and `TOP`/`ROWCOUNT`. I have no idea what your magic number would be, so you'll have to play with it, but the point is to cause minimal usage of the transaction log and, in simple recovery, issue multiple checkpoints in between iterations of the loop so that the log space you've used can be marked for reuse. (The process is slightly different in full recovery.)

So, for example (taken from [my blog post on this topic](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @r INT = 1;

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  DELETE TOP (10000) dbo.whatever WHERE ...;
  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  CHECKPOINT;
  CHECKPOINT;
END
```

(And no, the double `CHECKPOINT` is not a typo - it's become my habit based on [this comment from Robert Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log/18292136#comment26837713_18292136).)

Then, put your database on a disk that can handle it.